# Does continue statement really increases the speed of the loop in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, continue

So, I am new to online competitive programming and i came across a code where i am using the if else statement inside a for loop. I want to increase the speed of the loop and after doing some research i came across **break and continue** statements.

So my question is that does using **continue** really increases the speed of the loop or not.

**CODE :**

```
int even_sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
      if(i%4 == 0){
         even_sum +=i;
         continue;
      }else{
           //do other stuff when sum of multiple of 4 is not calculated
       }               
  }
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/, should generate the same code

Answer (score 3):

In the specific code in the question, the code has the identical meaning with and without the `continue`: In either case, after execution leaves `even_sum +=i;`, it flows to the closing `}` of the `for` statement. Any compiler of even modest quality should treat the two options identically.

The intended purpose of `continue` is not to speed up code by requesting a jump the compiler is going to make anyway but to skip code that is undesired in the current loop iteration—it acts as if the remaining code had been enclosed in an `else` clause but may be more visually appealing and less disruptive to human perception of the code.

It is conceivable a very rudimentary compiler, or even a decent compiler but with optimization disabled, might generate a jump instruction for the `continue` and also a jump instruction for the “then” clause of the `if` statement to jump over the `else` clause. The latter would never be executed and would have no direct effect on program execution time, but it would increase the size of the program and thus could have indirect effects. This possibility is of negligible concern in typical modern environments, where you are unlikely to encounter such a rudimentary compiler.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no speed advantage when using `continue` here. Both of your codes are identical and even [**without optimizations** they produce the same machine code](https://godbolt.org/z/iJmUGX).

However, sometimes `continue` can make your code a lot more efficient, if you have structured your loop in a specific way, e.g.

This:

```
int even_sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
        even_sum += i;
        continue;
    }
    if (huge_computation_but_always_false_when_multiple_of_4(i)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

is a lot more efficient, than:

```
int even_sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
        even_sum += i;
    }
    if (huge_computation_but_always_false_when_multiple_of_4(i)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

because the former doesn't have to execute the `huge_computation_but_always_false_when_multiple_of_4()` function every time.

So even though both of these codes would always produce the same result (given that `huge_computation_but_always_false_when_multiple_of_4()` has no side effects), the first one, which uses `continue`, would be a lot faster.

Comment: Changing the second `if` to `else if` does the same thing.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, obviously, this is just a rudementary example.